# Failled to install CUDA on my Ubuntu 19

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA for Deep Learning purposes and I have followed the instructions that can be find [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive).

Everything seems is going good but when finally I run the command `sudo apt-get install cuda-10-0` (same if I do not specify the CUDA version), I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-10-0 : Depends: cuda-runtime-10-0 (>= 10.0.130) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: cuda-demo-suite-10-0 (>= 10.0.130) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have searched similar errors on web but there is not something exactly like this.

## Edit:

I have tried to do it on the other way, using the `.run` file after accept the conditions of the License what I get is:
Installing the NVIDIA display driver...
The driver installation has failed due to an unknown error. Please consult the driver installation log located at /var/log/nvidia-installer.log.

```
Installing the NVIDIA display driver...
The driver installation has failed due to an unknown error. Please consult the driver installation log located at /var/log/nvidia-installer.log.

===========
= Summary =
===========

Driver:   Installation Failed
Toolkit:  Installation skipped
Samples:  Installation skipped
```

When I check the logs in that file I see:

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Wed May  6 14:12:03 2020
installer version: 410.48

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

nvidia-installer command line:
    ./nvidia-installer
    --ui=none
    --no-questions
    --accept-license
    --disable-nouveau
    --no-cc-version-check
    --run-nvidia-xconfig
    --dkms

Using built-in stream user interface
-> Detected 16 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 16.
ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia-drm' appears to already be loaded in your kernel.  This may be because it is in use (for example, by an X server, a CUDA program, or the NVIDIA Persistence Daemon), but this may also happen if your kernel was configured without support for module unloading.  Please be sure to exit any programs that may be using the GPU(s) before attempting to upgrade your driver.  If no GPU-based programs are running, you know that your kernel supports module unloading, and you still receive this message, then an error may have occured that has corrupted an NVIDIA kernel module's usage count, for which the simplest remedy is to reboot your computer.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

## Ubuntu 19:

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 19??  There is no Ubuntu 19.  Ubuntu desktop & server releases (based on *deb*s) use the *yy.mm* format, where as *snap* based release do use *yy* but are only released on even years (all *yy* releases are LTS such as Ubuntu Core 18 intended for IoT appliances/devices). Are you talking about a server/desktop release, or specialist release for appliances? as there is no Ubuntu 19.

Comment: @guiverc are you sure? See the edited post again.

Comment: That looks like Ubuntu 19.10 desktop release, a a *deb* based release, and not a *yy* based snap release (which doesn't have GUI except as *snap*)

Comment: Please, explain better.

Comment: *yy.mm* releases use *deb* files so can take `sudo apt` commands to install *deb* based packages as well as `sudo snap install` commands.  *yy* releases files use only the `snap install` commands as are *snap* based specialist releases.  Your picture shows your release as Ubuntu 19.10, which is a *deb* based system that can use *deb* files as well as *snaps*. They  are not the same system, the *yy* based systems are less flexible, but ideal for appliances & devices with limited cpu/memory usually found in IoT appliances/NAS/routers/TVs etc.  *yy.mm* based systems are usually found on computers

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades